# How to expand dims of my Keras layer and avoid using Lambda layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I' m using tensorflow.js and try to convert my keras model to tf.js model. However, it doesn't support Lambda layer which I try to use to convert tensorto layer(I use expand_dims) in my model(If not use it, model won't be created correctly, you know the reason). So I wonder if there is any way that I can avoid using Lambda layer and expand the dim of my embedding_layer.

```
# input layer
input_x = Input(shape=(sequence_length, ), dtype='int32')

# embedding layer
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size,
                            embedding_size,
                            embeddings_initializer=random_uniform(minval=-1.0, maxval=1.0))(input_x)
embedded_sequences = Lambda(lambda x: expand_dims(x, -1))(embedding_layer)
```

I'll appreciate it if you could give me some help, thanks!

Comment: https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.15.3/#expandDims

Comment: But my model is converted from Keras, so I can't expand dim of the model in js, it's fixed in "model.json".

Answer (score 7):

I solved it by myself.
Just use reshape.

```
from keras.backend import int_shape
        ......
        embedded_sequences = Reshape((int_shape(embedding_layer)[1], int_shape(embedding_layer)[2], 1))(embedding_layer)
        ......
```

You could expand dim without using expand_dims and Lambda layer.

Comment: there are many instances where the env prohibits use of a Lambda layer. What can be the reason?